# How do I find the handle owner from a hang dump using windbg?

Tags: windbg, deadlock, handle

How do I find out which thread is the owner of my Event handle in windbg:

I'm running

```
!handle 00003aec f
```

and get

```
Handle 00003aec
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
     Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
     QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  4
  Name          <none>
  No object specific information available
```

back, and as there is no Name I haven't figured out how to get the owner out to prove which thread my thread is waiting on

[Edit] I must work against a dump as the original process needs to be restarted on the users machine, so can't debug a live session

The best discussion on the subject I've found so far is on [this blog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/cdbntsd7.aspx), but unfortunately we end up using different lock methods (I end up using WaitForMultipleObjectsEx and the description is for WaitForSingleObject), and he seems to have access to a live process

the stacktrace of my thread (the one that is blocked on something and where I'm looking for the current owner) is:

```
0:045> k9
ChildEBP RetAddr 
1130e050 7c90e9ab ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
1130e054 7c8094e2 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
1130e0f0 79ed98fd kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
1130e158 79ed9889 mscorwks!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x6f
1130e178 79ed9808 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x3c
1130e1fc 79ed96c4 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c
1130e24c 79ed9a62 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
1130e2a8 79e78944 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0xf7
1130e2bc 7a162d84 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17
1130e33c 7a02fd94 mscorwks!CRWLock::RWWaitForSingleObject+0x6d
1130e364 79ebd3af mscorwks!CRWLock::StaticAcquireWriterLock+0x12e
1130e410 00f24557 mscorwks!CRWLock::StaticAcquireWriterLockPublic+0xc9
```

Comment: would you describe what your app is doing (i take it's .net but i'm not sure how you develop - c# or using managed c++ extensions?) and also, please provide stack with the first 3 args (kb) and probably provide insight as to what exactly the thread is (supposed to be) doing?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the callstack it appears that the stack in question is using a ReaderWriterLock locking mechanism.

```
1130e410 00f24557 mscorwks!CRWLock::StaticAcquireWriterLockPublic+0xc9
```

Change to thread 9 and using **sos.dll** run **!dso** to dump out the managed ReaderWriterLock object.  Then run !do on that the ReaderWriterLock object.  I believe that there is an owning thread field that you can query.  I will test it and see.

The old school way to determine this is to run **~*e !clrstack** and examine all of the managed threads that are waiting on a readerwriter lock and then see if you can find the thread that has entered the same function but passed through the lock (ie. different offset)

Thanks,
Aaron

Note: Not sure if there is a way to link posts but this one is very similar to
[How do I find the lockholder (reader) of my ReaderWriterLock in windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316894/how-do-i-find-the-lockholder-reader-of-my-readerwriterlock-in-windbg)

Comment: I didn't see a lock owner from !dso at the time, and doing a clrstack on all other threads doesn't show who has the lock as the owning thread is unlikely to still be running locking statements (it already has the lock and is doing real work somewhere, or is also blocked on another lock)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `!htrace` command to get the thread ID. You must first, possibly at the start of the program, enable the collection of traces with `!htrace -enable`.

```
0:001> !htrace 00003aec
--------------------------------------
Handle = 0x00003aec - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00000b48, Process ID = 0x000011e8

...
```

The above output is fictional, it will be different for your system. But it will give you the piece of information you need - the thread ID (0x00000b48 in my example).

> I must work against a dump as the
>   original process needs to be restarted
>   on the users machine, so can't debug a
>   live session.

I am not 100% sure but I think this will work:

1. Attach to the process and run `!htrace -enable`
2. Detach from the process with `qd`. The executable will continue.
3. You can now take a dump file and use the above command - I think you will have the described results.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig that out of a kernel dump.

Now, as far as kernel debugging goes, livekd from sysinternals should be sufficient but unfortunately it is only usable on a running system.

There's also a kernel mode [memory acquisition tool](http://win32dd.msuiche.net) which might be of use to take a dump with (in windbg's stead) for later inspection.

Otherwise, enabling handle tracing (!htrace -enable) and (if code unique to particular thread), the handle ownership could be concluded from a stack trace.

Comment: I can't use !htrace -enable as I need to grab the dump from a user's machine (and quickly restart so he can continue his work), otherwise it looks very promising

Answer (score 0):

Here's the definitive answer I found. Never tried myself. You'll need live debugging to determine the owner though. But it's pretty quick.
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/ingo/2006/08/who-is-blocking-that-mutex---fun-with-windbg-cdb-and-kd.html

Comment: The OP needs this for a hang dump, so this is hardly useful in this case.