# Get all IP-Hosts in Lan from mobile device

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, ping, lan

I want to get a list with all ip-addresses in my network, on a mobile device (C#.net compact framework).

I read through several articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042789/how-to-get-ip-all-hosts-in-lan) one. The problem is, that on my mobile device I can't ping them async cause I only have opennetcf which doesn't support it. And pinging it synchron takes too long.

Do you know a library which does this or do you know, how I can find out all hosts in my network, maybe even without pings (which is quite slow)

The port doesn't matter, I just want to know, which IPs are used...

Thank you, Karl

Comment: Bear in mind that often, hosts don't reply to pings. There is no one-size-fits-all way to enumerate network hosts. Hosts can even be configured to act as if they are not even powered up, from the perspective of a peer.