# UNET: Automatically hosting server or joining as client

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to avoid manually determining if the current instance of a running unity game is the host or client. Is there a way to detect existing games, and if there are join them, if there aren't start a host?

Note that players are not aware of networked content, so I cannot expect them to start an own host or pick an existing one to connect to.

I tried it with the `NetworkDiscovery` component as follows:

```
public class TestPlayerSetup : NetworkDiscovery {

  private float timeToWait = 1f;
  private float timeWaited = 0f;

  private bool hostDiscovered = false;

  void Start () {
    NetworkManager.singleton.networkAddress = "localhost";
    NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;

    Initialize ();
    StartAsClient ();
  }


  void Update() {

    if (timeWaited < timeToWait) {
      timeWaited += Time.deltaTime;
      return;
    }

    if (!hostDiscovered) {
      NetworkServer.Reset ();
      NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost ();
      StartAsServer ();
      hostDiscovered = true;
    }
  }

  public override void OnReceivedBroadcast(string fromAddress, string data){
    Debug.Log ("received broadcast");
    NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient();
    hostDiscovered = true;
    setPlayerColor ();
  }

}
```

But it seems you can't start a `NetworkDiscovery` server after having started a client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IP addresses of all devices in local network with Unity UNET in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951902/how-to-get-ip-addresses-of-all-devices-in-local-network-with-unity-unet-in-c)

Comment: If `NetworkDiscovery` does not work, use UDP to implement your own. See the the duplicated question for this.

Comment: @Programmer there is no way to get `NetworkDiscovery` to do this? UDP seems like a very complicated solution for a simple problem ..

Comment: *"But it seems you can't start a `NetworkDiscovery` server after having started a client."* Why do you  think this?

Comment: The above code returns that error (`StartAsServer ` fails because there is already a client running)

Comment: Here's the **full solution** https://forum.unity.com/threads/networkmanager-error-server-client-disconnect-error-1.439245/#post-3754939

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by removing the `NetworkDiscovery` component when no host is discovered when running as a client, and adding a new one to start the host:

```
private float timeToWait = 1f;
private float timeWaited = 0f;
private NetworkDiscovery serverNetwork;
private TestPlayerClient clientNetwork;
private bool serverStarted = false;
private bool hostDiscovered = false;

void Start () {
  NetworkManager.singleton.networkAddress = "localhost";
  NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;

  clientNetwork = gameObject.AddComponent<TestPlayerClient> ();
}

void Update() {

  if (timeWaited < timeToWait) {
    timeWaited += Time.deltaTime;
    return;
  }

  hostDiscovered = clientNetwork.hostDiscovered;
  if(clientNetwork != null && !hostDiscovered) {
    clientNetwork.StopBroadcast ();
    Destroy (clientNetwork);
    return;
  }

  if (!hostDiscovered && !serverStarted) {
    NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost ();
    serverNetwork = gameObject.AddComponent<NetworkDiscovery> ();
    serverNetwork.Initialize ();
    serverNetwork.StartAsServer ();
    serverStarted = true;
  }
}
```

`TestPlayerClient` code:

```
public class TestPlayerClient : NetworkDiscovery {

  public bool hostDiscovered {
    get;
    private set;
  }

    void Start () {
    Initialize ();
    StartAsClient ();
    Debug.Log ("trying client");
    hostDiscovered = false;
    }

  public override void OnReceivedBroadcast(string fromAddress, string data){
    Debug.Log ("broadcast received, starting client");
    StopBroadcast ();
    NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient();
    hostDiscovered = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The above code returns that error (StartAsServer fails because there
>   is already a client running)

Remove the `NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient();` function from the `OnReceivedBroadcast` function. That is trying to start a client each time `OnReceivedBroadcast` is called.

As for connecting to server automatically, do not do that. Instead, show player List of available servers and it's their job to pick one. Seperate your code into Server and Client code.

First of all, ignore the string `fromAddress` parameter in the `OnReceivedBroadcast` function. Don't use that.

*What to do on Server*:

On your server code, create a simple class to hold ip and port number of the server. Use Unity's [`JsonUtility`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity/36244111#36244111) to serialize the class and save it to `NetworkDiscovery.broadcastData`. You can now call `StartAsServer();`.

*What to do on Client*:

Create a `List` that holds that class that holds the ip and port of the server. Populate this `List` in the `OnReceivedBroadcast` function with the (`string data`) which is it's second parameter. Since it's a string, you have to use [`JsonUtility`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity/36244111#36244111) to convert it back to class. Only add it to the List if the ip and port is not in the `List`.

That's it. Players can then chose which server to connect to from that `List` which contains sever ip and port.

Comment: the purpose is exactly to host & connect automatically, so I cannot ignore that.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Make a game that automatically connects to a server. If there are two servers on the-same network, *automatically* connect to one even if player want's to connect to another one. Don't let the player connect to server they wish to. Note that I've answered why you are getting that error as StartClient is being called multiple times and which you should call once. Happy coding!